# refreshing the jquery mobile after getting the data using a json service

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JSON service which is given parameter like country="USA" ets and then it send the data in the JSON format.
I am using a page (url/index.html#page) where I take the parameter for the Json from user

I am able to show this data in a page URL/index.html#page3 but then when I come back to the #page2(above one) by clicking the back button and do a search like country="France" I still get the above results.

Now if i refresh my browser and try again with the Frnce it works fine!!!!... but i dont want this I want a solution for jquery mobile . Have been stuck on this for quite a while would be great if someone can help

Regards

Comment: `location.reload();` 
on data change

Comment: show us your code pls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `pageinit` event of `#page3` to populate code. That's why its firing only once. You need to use events like `pagebeforeshow` or `pageshow` to load data in `#page3` like this :

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page3", function() {
   //show loading message
   $.mobile.loading("show");

  //your ajax call to the server
  $.ajax({...

    success : function (d) { 
      //populate d in container
    }
  })
});
```